# Processing trip route table in C

Tags: beginner, c, sorting, homework

In fact, this is a group assignment for our C programming lesson, but seeking help from others is not considered cheating.

The goal of the following code is to:

1. Sort the data in `start.txt` by destination, and then by month if two trip routes share one destination.
2. Count how many trip routes each month and destination have.
3. Output the sorted data and the statistics to `result.txt`.

Since this is my first project, I want its coding style to be reviewed most of all. Also, please let me know if adding `register` or `restricted` somewhere can be benefitial, for I want to learn more about the use of modifiers in C. Of course, other optimisations are appreciated too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define MAX 500

typedef struct info
{
    unsigned num;
    char dest[80];
    unsigned length;
    char cat[80];
    unsigned month;
    unsigned price;
} info;

size_t readIn(info *s);
void   overallSort(info *s, size_t itemNum);
size_t groupByDest(info *s, size_t firstItemIndex, size_t itemNum);
void   sortByMonth(info *s, size_t lowerBound, size_t upperBound);
void   countRouteMonth(info *s, size_t itemNum, unsigned *numEachMonth);
void   countRouteKind(info *s, size_t itemNum, unsigned *numEachDest);
void   output(info *s, size_t itemNum, unsigned *numEachMonth, unsigned *numEachDest);

int main(void)
{
    size_t itemNum;
    struct info s[MAX];
    unsigned numEachMonth[12];
    unsigned numEachDest[MAX] = {0};
    itemNum = readIn(s);
    overallSort(s, itemNum);
    countRouteMonth(s, itemNum, numEachMonth);
    countRouteKind(s, itemNum, numEachDest);
    output(s, itemNum, numEachMonth, numEachDest);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    fwide(stdout, 1);
    fputwc(L'\uFEFF', stdout);
    wprintf(L"\u4E34\u7801\u6D95\u96F6\uFF0C\u4E0D\u77E5\u6240\u8A00\u3002\n");
    wprintf(L"\u5E78\u751A\u81F3\u54C9\uFF0C\u6B4C\u4EE5\u548F\u5FD7\u3002\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

size_t readIn(struct info *s)
{
    unsigned itemCount = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen("start.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Opening start.txt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char buffer[80];
    while(fgets(buffer, 80, fp))
    {
        sscanf(buffer, " %u %s %u %s %u %u", &s[itemCount].num, s[itemCount].dest, &s[itemCount].length, s[itemCount].cat, &s[itemCount].month, &s[itemCount].price);
        itemCount++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return itemCount;
}

void overallSort(info *s, size_t itemNum)
{
    size_t destIndex = 0;
    while(destIndex < itemNum)
    {
        destIndex += groupByDest(s, destIndex, itemNum);
    }
}

size_t groupByDest(info *s, size_t firstItemIndex, size_t itemNum)
{
    info temp;
    size_t i, j = firstItemIndex + 1, groupSize = 1;
    for(i = firstItemIndex + 1; i < itemNum; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(s[i].dest, s[firstItemIndex].dest) == 0)
        {
            if(i != j)
            {
                temp = s[j];
                s[j] = s[i];
                s[i] = temp;
            }
            j++;
            groupSize++;
        }
    }
    sortByMonth(s, firstItemIndex, firstItemIndex + groupSize - 1);
    return groupSize;
}

void sortByMonth(info *s, size_t lowerBound, size_t upperBound)
{
    info temp;
    size_t i, j;
    for(i = lowerBound; i < upperBound; i++)
    {
        for(j = lowerBound; j < upperBound; j++)
        {
            if(s[j].month > s[j+1].month)
            {
                temp = s[j];
                s[j] = s[j + 1];
                s[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void countRouteMonth(info *s, size_t itemNum, unsigned *numEachMonth)
{
    size_t i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < itemNum; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            if(s[i].month == j + 1)
            {
                numEachMonth[j]++;
            }
    }
}

void countRouteKind(info *s, size_t itemNum, unsigned *numEachDest)
{
    size_t i, num = 1, DestIndex = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < itemNum; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(s[i].dest, s[i + 1].dest) == 0)
        {
            num++;
        }
        else
        {
            numEachDest[DestIndex] = num;
            DestIndex++;
            num = 1;
        }
    }
}

void output(struct info *s, size_t itemNum, unsigned *numEachMonth, unsigned *numEachDest)
{
    size_t i, destIndex = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen("result.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Opening result.txt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "Number\tDest\tDays\tCat\t\tMonth\tPrice\n");
    for(i = 0; i < itemNum; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%u\t%s\t%u\t%s\t%u\t%u\n", s[i].num, s[i].dest, s[i].length, s[i].cat, s[i].month, s[i].price);
    }

    fputc('\n', fp);
    fprintf(fp, "STATISTICS:\n");
    fputc('\n', fp);
    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "The number of the routes in month %zu is %u.\n", i + 1, numEachMonth[i]);
    }
    fputc('\n', fp);
    for(i = 0; numEachDest[i]; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "The number of the routes to %s is %u.\n", s[destIndex].dest, numEachDest[i]);
        destIndex += numEachDest[i];
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

`start.txt` contains:

> ```
> 1 Guilin  7   Domestic    2   9857
> 2 Suzhou  7   Domestic    1   47893
> 3 Wuxi    3   Domestic    3   41525
> 4 Tibet   4   Domestic    4   13123
> 5 Guilin  5   Domestic    7   5532
> 6 Wuxi    6   Domestic    8   232
> 7 Suzhou  7   Domestic    9   132132
> 8 Wuxi    8   Domestic    4   343432
> 9 Suzhou  9   Domestic    12  24234
> 10    Jinan   10  Domestic    5   42334
> 11    Wuxi    7   Domestic    6   15156
> 12    Tibet   3   Domestic    10  25425
> 13    Tibet   4   Domestic    11  35345
> 14    Tibet   5   Domestic    12  34453
> 15    Suzhou  6   Domestic    3   34345
> 16    Jinan   7   Domestic    5   8785
> 17    Suzhou  8   Domestic    6   334533
> 18    Jinan   9   Domestic    7   4653
> 19    Wuxi    10  Domestic    9   34234
> 20    Wuxi    7   Domestic    10  2432423
> 21    Jinan   3   Domestic    1   43432
> 22    Tibet   4   Domestic    11  87678
> 23    Suzhou  5   Domestic    5   78878
> 24    Suzhou  6   Domestic    7   7826
> 25    Jinan   7   Domestic    12  2132
> 26    Tibet   8   Domestic    3   464656
> 27    Wuxi    9   Domestic    8   9857
> 28    Tibet   10  Domestic    9   47893
> 29    Tibet   7   Domestic    2   41525
> 30    Jinan   3   Domestic    6   13123
> 31    Suzhou  4   Domestic    7   5532
> 32    Guilin  5   Domestic    3   232
> 33    Guilin  6   Domestic    4   132132
> 34    Guilin  7   Domestic    5   343432
> 35    Wuxi    8   Domestic    9   24234
> 36    Guilin  9   Domestic    10  42334
> 37    Suzhou  10  Domestic    11  15156
> 38    Wuxi    7   Domestic    2   25425
> 39    Suzhou  3   Domestic    3   35345
> 40    Guilin  4   Domestic    6   34453
> 41    Munich  5   International       7   34345
> 42    Dubai   6   International       5   8785
> 43    London  7   International       6   334533
> 44    Paris   8   International       9   4653
> 45    Vienna  9   International       8   34234
> 46    Moscow  10  International       11  2432423
> 47    Berlin  7   International       12  43432
> 48    Tokyo   3   International       10  87678
> 49    Sydney  4   International       9   78878
> 50    Madrid  5   International       8   7826
> 51    Munich  6   International       7   2132
> 52    Dubai   7   International       6   464656
> 53    London  8   International       5   9857
> 54    Paris   9   International       4   47893
> 55    Vienna  10  International       7   41525
> 56    Moscow  7   International       5   13123
> 57    Berlin  3   International       3   5532
> 58    Tokyo   4   International       2   232
> 59    Sydney  5   International       1   132132
> 60    Madrid  6   International       4   343432
> 61    Munich  7   International       5   24234
> 62    Dubai   8   International       6   42334
> 63    London  9   International       7   15156
> 64    Paris   10  International       9   25425
> 65    Vienna  7   International       1   35345
> 66    Moscow  3   International       2   34453
> 67    Berlin  4   International       10  34345
> 68    Tokyo   5   International       11  8785
> 69    Sydney  6   International       12  334533
> 70    Madrid  7   International       11  4653
> 71    Munich  8   International       9   34234
> 72    Dubai   9   International       5   2432423
> 73    London  10  International       6   43432
> 74    Paris   7   International       7   87678
> 75    Vienna  3   International       2   78878
> 76    Moscow  4   International       3   7826
> 77    Berlin  5   International       4   2132
> 78    Tokyo   6   International       5   464656
> 79    Sydney  7   International       8   9857
> 80    Madrid  8   International       9   47893
> 81    Munich  9   International       10  41525
> 82    Dubai   10  International       3   13123
> 83    London  7   International       4   5532
> 84    Paris   3   International       5   232
> 85    Vienna  4   International       8   132132
> 86    Moscow  5   International       4   343432
> 87    Berlin  6   International       8   24234
> 88    Tokyo   7   International       1   42334
> 89    Sydney  8   International       7   15156
> 90    Madrid  9   International       7   25425
> 91    Munich  10  International       7   35345
> 92    Dubai   7   International       7   34453
> 93    London  3   International       4   34345
> 94    Paris   4   International       3   8785
> 95    Vienna  5   International       2   334533
> 96    Moscow  6   International       6   4653
> 97    Berlin  7   International       7   34234
> 98    Tokyo   8   International       9   2432423
> 99    Sydney  9   International       8   43432
> 100   Madrid  10  International       10  87678
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally to the variable-naming that was already mentioned:

- Put "magic constants" into defines:

  - `#define BUFLEN 80`, `#define INPUT_FILE "start.txt"` etc.
- `readIn()` etc. will perhaps in future be re-used with different filenames -- so prefer giving them as a parameter rather than relying on globals.
- Preference: Use function name in parameter to `perror()`, eg.:

  ```
  if((fp = fopen(INPUT_FILE, "r")) == NULL) {
      perror(__func__);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ```

  if you want to not only display the function called you can use.

  ```
  fprintf(stderr, __func__ "%s, \"r\"": %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
  ```

  This is much more useful information, imho (Thanks to @chux for the hint with the `__func__`-macro)
- I find this hard to read:

  ```
  size_t i, j = firstItemIndex + 1, groupSize = 1;
  ```

  Why not seperate the declarations and put `i` into the following for statement (not only here)?

  ```
  size_t j = firstItemIndex +1, groupSize = 1;
  for (size_t i = firstItemIndex +1, ...
  ```

  - Also I find the logic here hard to folow -- why are you initializing `i` to the value of `firstItemIndex + 1 + 1`? This might make sense but not without trying to go through your code line-by-line.
- `strcmp()` compares two strings -- and if they don't differ it will go on, until it reads the terminating `'\0'`-character. Sadly, if both strings are longer than their buffer its results are unpredictable. Use `strncmp()` instead and give it a maximum length to compare!
- Be consistent: sometimes you use `struct info`, sometimes just `info`. As the latter is `typedef`-ed to the former you could always omit the `struct`. This is personal preference but use either (I prefer not omitting the struct if I'm not dealing with *many* as this obfuscates code less, imho again).
- Separate different code sections like processing, output, etc. with empty lines. This makes it more easy to understand that these are distinct. Example: Add a newline after `output(...)` in `main()`.
- You are iterating using a `size_t` type but writing the result to an `unsigned`:

  ```
  $ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow main.c -o main
  main.c: In function ‘countRouteKind’:
  main.c:133:29: warning: conversion to ‘unsigned int’ from ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
      numEachDest[DestIndex] = num;
                               ^~~
  ```
- [PERSONAL PREFERENCE] Use `unsigned int` instead of just `unsigned`.
- *[PERSONAL PREFERENCE]* Variable naming: You use "camelCase". In C usually "snake_case" is preferred. It's nothing bad, but I like to stick with the style a language has as it makes things more consistent.
- *[PERSONAL PREFERENCE]* Most C programmers I know prefer code to have a limited line width (like 80 chars). While modern screens of course easily fit more than this limit, it makes it nicer to have multiple editors of code open. If you think 80 chars is not enough, set your limit to 100, 120 or whatever your institution uses.

Otherwise I think you did good -- it's definitely not what I'd consider ugly code or similar, don't be intimidated by the number of changes I suggest, these are just minor things ;)

Comment: Instead of `"fopen()"`, maybe `_ _func_ _`?

Comment: Concerning line presentation width.  I suggest using the width of the review forum.  So if horizontal scrolls bars come up here, then code is too wide.  The _true_ source code width should be limited as you suggest.

Comment: @chux Cool, didn't know about thay macro, thanks!

Comment: @chux Concerning the 2nd point: This'd require reformatting the code, so while a nice gesture, I think we cannot ask for that ^^

Answer (score 3):

**Naming**

Structure/variable naming is one of the most effective ways you have of making your code self documenting.  It's always worth taking some time to consider your names, this becomes more important the wider the usage of the names.  You have names like **s**, **info**, **num** for your most important structure, its members and references to it.  These are far from descriptive and are worth reconsidering.

You also have method names like `readin`, `output`, what are these methods reading/writing, to where?

**Overflow**

You `readin` method loops through a file, reading into a constantly sized structure buffer.  If the file contains more lines than the number of buffer elements it will overflow.  You should be checking that `itemCount` < MAX.

**Error checking**

Your `readin` method is using sscanf to parse the contents of the file.  You're not checking it's return value, what are you expecting it to do if you get passed a line that's not the correct format?

**Bracing**

This is subjective, but I don't really like this:

```
for(j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    if(s[i].month == j + 1)
    {
```

It's error prone if you decide you need to extra behaviour to the for loop and forget to add the braces when you do.  I'd prefer to see braces wrapping the for loop...

Comment: Could you please give me some specfic suggestions on variable namimg? I just don't know what's good names for important variables :(

Comment: @sunqingyao 'num' might be 'routeIdentifier', 'info' might be 'routeRecord', 's' could be'routes'.  The point is to try and name it for what it represents (which I may well have misinterpreted in my examples).